# GPG error The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, debian

I'm following [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/) guide for the installation of Docker inside a Jenkins container

This is the Dockerfile of the Jenkins container:

```
FROM jenkins:1.596
 
USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

# setup docker repository
RUN apt-get install
RUN apt-get update

RUN echo "deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-transport-https \
    && ca-certificates \
    && curl \
    && gnupg-agent \
    && software-properties-common

RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88

RUN add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
   
# install docker engine
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

USER jenkins
```

When I build the image I get these errors:

```
Reading package lists...
W: GPG error: http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9D6D8F6BC857C906 NO_PUBKEY AA8E81B4331F7F50
W: GPG error: http://http.debian.net jessie-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
W: GPG error: http://http.debian.net jessie Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem:

```
 the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
```

Debian, just try :

```
sudo apt-get install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring

sudo apt-key update

sudo apt-get update
```

Or, you should add the below in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins:1.596

USER root

RUN apt-get install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring

RUN apt-key update

RUN apt-get update
```

Comment: The first code block worked perfectly for me in a different situation whilst setting up a new raspberry pi when attempting to install unrar

Comment: Thank you for your Vote and feedback! @Syrus bro, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The apt has a set of trusted keys and sometimes we only need to add the ones that are missing.

You can add the missing keys just by running the following command:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 9D6D8F6BC857C906 AA8E81B4331F7F50 7638D0442B90D010
```

Then, the start of your Dockerfile could be something like this:

```
FROM jenkins:1.596

USER root
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 9D6D8F6BC857C906 AA8E81B4331F7F50 7638D0442B90D010
RUN apt-get update
...
```

Greetings.